# replacing toggle with another graphic when open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to replace my toggle button with an 'X' when it opens the mobile navigation. My navigation/website utilizes the Bootstrap 3 framework

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-header">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>        

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button> 

</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
  background-color:#333;
  transition: background-color 0.75s ease;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  border-radius:0;
  border:none;
}
```

Comment: user3550879 what have you tried that didn't work? Please be specific, the more details you give the community, the better chance to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the `span` inside of it and toggle the text. Try it:

```js
$('#toggleNav').click(function(){
  var txt = ( $(this).text().trim(' ') == 'X' ) ? 'Toggle navigation' : 'X';
  $( '.sr-only', $(this) ).text(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Removed irrelevant HTML -->

<button id="toggleNav"> 
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
    <span></span>
</button>
```

**Edit:** Since you are already using jQuery, all you need to do is put this anywhere in your `<head>` or `<body>`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Code goes here
    });
</script>
```

This will make sure the button is loaded when it looks for it. Also make sure to use an ID on your button, and to reflect that in the JS.

Comment: can I put that javascript anywhere (in my head tags)?

Comment: so I replace .this with the id I give my button then?

Comment: @user3550879 No, you replace `$('#toggleNav')` with `$('#yourIDGoesHere')`